# Why can't I upload a new profile picture using the iOS application?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I just took a picture of myself using my iPhone, but I can't upload it using this application. I'd like this to be possible very much though, is there any room for consideration?

PS: willing to make a pun like 'seeing the bigger **picture** of this feature.'

Comment: It requires lots of efforts, which are better spent elsewhere, since editing profile is easily done via the full site. The main obstacle is the API, not the app itself.